# How can I make my single insta-feed row into 2 columns on my Mobile version?

Tags: css, instagram, shopify, grid-layout

My Instafeed is showing as a single row on my mobile, But I want it to show as 3 rows and 2 columns instead of just one column with 5 posts. How can I go about this? I have tried using? Help would be much appreciated.[this is how my instagram feed currently look like on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS48k.jpg) and this [is how I want it to appear on mobile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hx6p.jpg)

**CSS:**

```
#instafeed .instagram__item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .instagram__item:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
  }

  .instagram__link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .instagram__bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .instagram__video-link {
    &:after, &:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    &:after {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: 16px solid transparent;
      border-left: 20px solid #fff;
      margin-top: -18px;
      margin-left: -7px;
      -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
    }
    &:before {
      margin-top: -34px;
      margin-left: -34px;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border: 3px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(black, 0.18);
      background: rgba(black, 0.42);
      transition: background 0.3s ease;
    }
    &:hover {
      &:before {
        background: rgba(black, 0.7);
      }
    }
  }

  .social-feeds-wrap {
    .sixteen {
      .columns:nth-child(4n + 1){
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .columns:nth-child(4n + 4){
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
    .eight {
      .columns:nth-child(odd){
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .columns:nth-child(even){
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Remove unwanted code